# Applying a transformation to each row of a custom column created by Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

## Summary of problem:

I need each row of a query's custom column to populate based on a formula referencing cells within the query, as well as values from a different worksheet. What is the best way to do this?

### Original Post:

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days, and connot figure it out. I'm making a task-management workbook that sorts data based on which week of our program you submit your action items. **What this tries to do is to return which week of my program an entry belongs to.** I.e. if 23 days have passed since the start, then an entry belongs to week 3. If 76 days have passed, then its week 7. This is important because I use the result when filtering for a report macro.

[This is the query table I need to add the calculation to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bqCI.png)

The last column is the custom column, and those values should be calculated using the following cells:
[This is the source of the other info needed to calculate the week number of the program, with references shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHfJ0.png)

The approach I take works fine if there's only one row, but the named cell returns #VALUE! when it reloads if there is more than one new row in the custom column. I think this is because the cell I'm referencing is a formula with a variable that has multiple values? I'm relatively new to PQ so please be patient.

The Transformation I'm trying to perform/the formula in the named cell I want to apply to each row of the new column is:

```
=IFS(AND($B$2<WEEKNUM(New_Items_to_Save[Start Date]),WEEKNUM(New_Items_to_Save[Start Date])<54),$G$2-($D$2-(-53+WEEKNUM(New_Items_to_Save[Start Date]))),WEEKNUM(New_Items_to_Save[Start Date])<$B$2,$G$2-($D$2+WEEKNUM(New_Items_to_Save[Start Date])))
```

Which, using the above picture, solves to:
=IFS(AND(33<[WeeknumStart Date], [Start Date]<54),47-(26-(-53+[WeeknumStart Date])), [WeeknumStart Date]<33, 47-(26+[WeeknumStart Date]))

AND: if the date falls within the range of the current year ie. week# is less than 54, then perform this calc.

IFS: otherwise, if week# is before the end of the program ie. 2023, then perform this calculation.

The above formula definitely works if I replace the "New_Items_to_Save[Start Date]" with a specific cell, so I don't think it's that. Maybe I'm not referring to it correctly? I'm not sure how parameters work or how to create new functions, but I can troubleshoot/google reasonably well.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It could be just me but I don't follow. You somehow have a date and then pull in a variable week started. Whats the transformation supposed to be doing?  Maybe edit your question to post sample of starting data and desired output

Comment: @horseyride is that any clearer?

Comment: Subtracting the start date of a program from a week number does not seems to make sense. So, no, not clearer. I dont understand the unwillingness or difficulty in posting a sample of starting data and desired output.

Comment: Why not perform the transformation within Power Query?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am completely open to that, I just don't know how to do that. My experience writing M code is nigh non-existent.

If you have any suggestions, I'm all ears! Thank you

Comment: @horseyride ahh I see your point. The dates of the program starting are already converted into their corresponding weeknumber (see "Start Week Number" and "End Week Number"). That was the only way I could compare the two numbers; as you pointed out, subtracting a date from a weeknumber doesn't make sense. Please let me know if you need more info. I'd be happy to upload the whole thing if you thought it would help?

Comment: At this point, I think I'll let some other helpful person chime in

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be using a combination of the PowerQuery in-build date functions (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-functions)) and some of the PowerQuery conditional processes (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-conditionals)).

I've given some extensive examples for how to address this problem in your other question on this topic; please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718433/applying-function-to-each-row-in-query-custom-column/74883447#74883447).